# Applying the hampel filter to a df in python

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am currently trying to apply the hampel filter to my dataframe in python, I have looked around and there isn't a lot of documentation for its implementation in python. I found one post but it looks like it was created **before** there was an actual hampel package/function and someone created a function to do a rolling mean calculation not using the filter from the package itself, even the site for Hampel the package is minimal. I am looking at the number of Covid cases per day by fips code. I have 470 time series (in days)  data frame, each column is a different FIPS code and each row has the number of Covid cases per day (with dates, not the day number from start). The package for Hampel is very straight forward, it has two options for outputs, it will either return a list of the indices where it thinks there are outliers or it will replace the outliers with the median with in the data.

- the two codes for using the hampel are:

[IN]:

```
ts = pd.Series([1, 2, 1 , 1 , 1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 2, 15, 1, 2])
```

[IN]:  # to return indices:

```
outlier_indices = hampel(ts, window_size=5, n=3)
print("Outlier Indices: ", outlier_indices)
```

[OUT]:

```
Outlier Indices:  [6, 10]
```

[IN]: # to return series with rolling medians replaced*** I'm using this format

```
ts_imputation = hampel(ts, window_size=5, n=3, imputation=True)
ts_imputation
```

[OUT]:

```
0     1.0
1     2.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     1.0
5     2.0
6     2.0
7     2.0
8     1.0
9     2.0
10    2.0
11    1.0
12    2.0
dtype: float64
```

So with my data frame I want it to replace the outliers in each column with the column median, I am using a window = 21 and a threshold = 6 (b/c of the data setup). I should mention each of the column starts with a different number of 0's for the rows. So for example the value for the  first 80 rows for column one may be 0's and then for column 2 the first 95 rows may have 0's because each FIPs code has a diffferent number of days   Given this I tried to use the .apply method with the following fx:

```
[IN]:
def hamp(col):
    no_out = hampel(col, window_size=21, n=6, imputation=True)
    return (no_out)

[IN]:
  df = df.apply(hamp2, axis=1)
```

**However, when I printed my data frame is now just all 0's.** Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: `axis=1` is for rows, so if you need `hamp(col)` to take columns, change to `axis=0` (or remove `axis` since 0 is default)

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel so dumb for this one lol

Comment: no problem! fyi you can also use the more semantic aliases `axis='index'` and `axis='columns'`

Answer (score 0):

recently SKTIME added HampelFilter

```
from sktime.transformations.series.outlier_detection import HampelFilter
y = your_data
transformer = HampelFilter(window_length=10)
y_hat = transformer.fit_transform(y)
```

also you can read the documentation here [HampelFilter_sktime](https://www.sktime.net/en/stable/api_reference/auto_generated/sktime.transformations.series.outlier_detection.HampelFilter.html)